# Error while loading page from Appname. Empty response received

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, fbml

I'm desperate. I've installed a new SSL certificate (with Geotrust) and when I try to access to my fmbl app through https connection I can't see the application, the page shows me the next error: "Empty response received." What can I do? Is the second SSL where I tried it, and the people is rating badly the app that was with near to 5 stars...

However, if I access to the app through http (non ssl) I can see the app without problems.

Help me please :/